# How to init provider?

Tags: dart, flutter-provider, riverpod

The case is: i am going to use MyProvider in the following way `SomeProvidersClass.get().myProvider;` from this structure:

```
class SomeProvidersClass {
late final myProvider =
    Provider((ref) => MyProvider());

MyProvider get myProvider =>
    read(providers.myProvider);
}
```

But
i heed to MyProvider be initialized via some async function;
so i tried to do it in the following way:

```
class MyProvider {
  late final SomeType _someVariable; // need to init in async way

  Future<void> init() async => _someVariable = await SomeType.getInstance();

  MyProvider();

  // example of content of this provider that i am going to use
  dynamic? getSmth() => _someVariable.getSmth();

}
```

and i got the following error

```
LateInitializationError: field has not been initialized;
```

Could you suggest me any approach to do it? i am new in riverpod and providers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
class MyProvider {
  SomeType? _someVariable; // need to init in async way

  Future<void> init() async => _someVariable = await SomeType.getInstance();

  MyProvider(){
    init();
  }

  // example of content of this provider that i am going to use
  dynamic? getSmth() => _someVariable?.getSmth();

}
```

Comment: when i should call init()?

Comment: I made an edit, you can call it in the constructor.

Comment: oh okay thanks!!

Comment: Kindly accept and upvote if it works for you.